# Get drag event from flash object in javascript?

Tags: jquery, flash, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a draggable instance of FlowPlayer using jQuery, but I can't get any mouse events to work over the Flash object.

If wmode is 'opaque' or 'window' I only have mouse events working inside the flash object, whereas with wmode set to 'transparent' I get the mouse events in jQuery but not in the flash object...does anyone know if there is a way to have mouse events working in both?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is to use `ExternalInterface` in Flash to pass the mouse events to JS.

Another solution is to overlay a div on the Flash to capture and block the mouse event to Flash. Since you're using a Flash video player, blocking the mouse events on the video display area should be fine. Just don't block the playback buttons :P